# Passing through $this into function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass through a reference to an item selected by the user (so that the appropriate Javascript effects can be run on it), but it doesn't seem to be working. Initially it was, but when I refactored my code to make it easier to read, it stopped. I reckon it is an issue with the logic I am using, can anyone please show me how to correct it.

**New code - not working but easier to read**

```
$('.timeline-item').click(function() {
    expandTimelineDetail( $(this));
});

function expandTimelineDetail($obj) {
     // UI effect
     $obj = $(this).css("background-color", "#F5F5F5");
     setTimeout(function () {
         $obj.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
     }, 250);

     // Make timeline item active
     $obj.addClass("active-item");
     $obj.next().addClass("active-item").css('display', 'block');

     // Hide the rest of the timeline items that are not active
     $('#timeline > :not(.active-item)').hide();
     $('#leftspan').css('visibility', 'visible');
     $('.search-container').css('display', 'none');

     // Hide relative departure time, show actual departure time
     $('.actual-time').css('display', 'inline');
     $('.leaving-time').css('display', 'none');
}
```

**Old code - working fine but difficult to read**

```
$('.timeline-item').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this).css("background-color","#F5F5F5");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
        }, 250);
        $(this).addClass("active-item");
        $(this).next().addClass("active-item").css('display','block');
        $('#timeline > :not(.active-item)').hide();
        $('#leftspan').css('visibility','visible');
        $('.search-container').css('display','none');
        $('.actual-time').css('display','inline');
        $('.leaving-time').css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: Don't overwrite the value of $obj with "$obj = $(this).css("background-color", "#F5F5F5");". Also, why not just $('.timeline-item').click(expandTimelineDetail);? Then you can use $(this) instead of $obj.

Comment: when you pass $(this).  $(this) = $obj.

Comment: @bobdye - the full code is actually makes a call to a number of other functions. Have a look here http://pastebin.com/xtmmeC4j

Comment: just get rid of `$obj=$(this)` Inside your function `this` has no context and will actually be `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `$(this)` to the function where you assign another value to `$obj` argument.

You can bind `this` to function:

```
expandTimelineDetail.bind(this);
```

Where you will be able to access `this` as you did before

Or just don't reassign `$obj` variable.